# Infinite Sum involving Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: summation, orthogonal-polynomials

I would like to simplify (if possible)

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-\alpha)^k\frac{(2k)!\:L(2k,-\beta)}{k!}
$$

where $L(n,x)$ is the $n$-th Laguerre polynomial evaluated at $x$. In this case, I know that $0<\alpha<1$ and $\beta>0$, but this sum only seems to converge numerically for very small $\alpha$ (which is fine, I'm assuming there are restrictions on these constants).

EDIT: This appears to not even converge.

Comment: The Laguerre polynomials can be written in closed form as $\displaystyle L_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$. Consequently the summation becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-\alpha)^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!}\:L_{2k}(-\beta)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^k (-\alpha)^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!}\binom{2k}{n}\frac{\beta^{n}}{n!}.$$ I can't see how to proceed from here; perhaps someone else can...

Comment: I think your second sum should go to $2k$, but yeah I played around with this form and it didn't seem to work. The closest thing I have found is $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-\alpha )^k L_k(x)= \frac{e^{\frac{\alpha  x}{\alpha +1}}}{\alpha +1}$.

Comment: I cannot see how it may happen to converge, either. $L(2k,0)=1$ and $\sum_{k\geq 0}(-\alpha)^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!}$ is not converging for any $\alpha\neq 0$.

Comment: Hm, you may be right, I may not have checked enough terms!